# I'm getting empty request body in express.js

Tags: javascript, express

I'm trying to get my data in my database but not getting anything in the body of the request. I have used parse-body and CORS but it still not working.
I tried several things but did not work.
Backend code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const port = 5000;

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://ishadDB@cluster0.gi4fd.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
client.connect((err) => {
  const bookings = client.db("BurjAlArab").collection("bookings");
  console.log("Connected");

  app.post('/addBooking', (req, res) => {
      console.log(req)
    const newBooking = req.body;
    console.log(newBooking);
    bookings.insertOne(newBooking)
      .then(res => {
         res.send(result.insertedCount > 0);
      });
  });
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

app.listen(port);
```

front end:

```
const handleBooking = () => {
    const newBooking = { ...loggedInUser, ...selectedDate };
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/addBooking', {
      method: 'POST',
      header: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
      body : JSON.stringify({newBooking})
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  };
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: did you check if you reach to that endpoint (/addBooking) anyway?

Comment: never saw somebody putting `app.(...)` inside the callback of the connect

Comment: I get only a object id in my mongo db. The request body is empty.

Comment: I am getting error to the endpoint "/addBooking"

Comment: I am new so consider my mistakes

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Not getting anything in the post request that I made.

Comment: Ah okay, try out the code snippet from my answer and tell me if you receive something

Comment: what is the output of this ** console.log(newBooking);** in your app.post ?

Comment: ** console.log(newBooking);** is okay. I am getting all the data i need but in the mongo database I am getting only the unique id and the output in the backend file is also an empty object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send it in your frontend with the **following code**

This take use of **[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)**

Notice because of the use of **await** the function have to be **async**
`async function bla(){}`

```
async function bla(){
    const data = {newBooking};
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        };
        await fetch('/addBooking', options); 
    }
}
```